# Are there any advantages to sleeping longer?

Tags: fallout-3

In Fallout 3, sleeping in your own bed for just one hour gives you a well rested bonus and heals you. Is there any benefit to sleeping for longer (like having the well rested bonus for more hours)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, no, sleeping longer does not give you anything that a short sleep does not.

It does allow you to change the time of day to the time you want for particular events.